# Yield n times in a method not working?

Tags: ruby, methods, block

An example of what I'm trying to do is probably best:

```
def repeater(n = 1)
  n.times { yield }
end
```

By default, repeater will go through the block given once. However, I want it to go through the block multiple times if given n > 1. For some reason the above code doesn't work.

For instance:

I would expect this to result in `64`, but instead it returns `5`:

```
y = 2
repeater(5) { y *= 2 }
```

Why is this happening? Where am I going wrong? I'm fairly new to `yield`, and don't understand it entirely (clearly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the return value of `repeater` is the return value of `times`, which will always be `n`, so you should interrogate the resulting value of `y` itself instead:

```
y = 2
repeater(5) { y *= 2 }  #=> 5
y  #=> 64
```

If you want `repeater` to actually return the final result, you could [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) over a [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html):

```
def repeater(n = 1)
  (0..n).reduce { yield }
end

y = 2
repeater(5) { y *= 2 }  #=> 64
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `yield`. The function returns a result of `n.times { … }` which is obviously equals `5`:

```
> 5.times { }
# => 5
```

You want to accumulate the result of yield and explicitely return it from your function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using the `times` method as I was attempting to do:

```
def repeater(n = 1)
  (n - 1).times { yield }
  yield
end
```

The above looks nice, as I wanted, but I was hoping I could do this with `n.times` instead of `(n - 1).times`.

The following is a solution using that, but it doesn't look elegant:

```
def repeater(n = 1)
  result = nil
  n.times {result = yield}
  result
end
```

I'll attempt to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why not see my answer above for an elegant, one-line solution…

Comment: I like your answer. I was just attempting to solve it using `times`.